Why does memory error appear with unsafe code in c#
I prepare some little code snippet hereunder that represent my real world buged code.
byte count = 100;
byte* pointer = &count;
(*(ushort*)pointer) = (ushort)byte.MaxValue;

I found error in third row and fix it. *pointer = byte.MaxValue;
But I dont understand exactly why fault code sometimes run without error and sometimes failed with error:
malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

I see that instruction (*(ushort*)pointer) = (ushort)byte.MaxValue; write two bytes in memory and second memory cell here may be used for other variables of current process or other processes.
Why sometimes error does not throw?
May be it run normally if second byte is "free"?
Or may be it throws only if second byte is owned by other process and is refers to other address space?

Why are you mucking around with raw pointers in the first place, what is your use case?

(*(ushort*)pointer) = (ushort)byte.MaxValue; attempts to write 2 bytes via a pointer which actually points to 1 bytes.
The result is undefined behavior.
The example here for undefined behavior (under 23.5 Pointer conversions, 23.5.1 General), is showing a similar case:
unsafe static void M()
{
    char c = 'A';
    char* pc = &c;
    void* pv = pc;
    int* pi = (int*)pv; // pretend a 16-bit char is a 32-bit int
    int i = *pi;        // read 32-bit int; undefined
    *pi = 123456;       // write 32-bit int; undefined
}

In cases of undefined behavior [almost] anything can happen, including (but not necessarily) getting an error. The program might also seem to work as expected, but you should not count on it.
Regarding:

Or may be it throws only if second byte is owned by other process and
is refers to other address space?

Each process has its own address space (on Windows see: Virtual Address Space) and a process cannot access the address space of another process like that.
So this is not relevant on your case (there are special Win32 apis for accessing a diffrent address space in certain cases - e.g. WriteProcessMemory, but it is not something you can trivially do like in your posted code).

small clarification.
In unmanaged code, is it impossible to access a memory cell of another process's address space? I can't assign an arbitrary address to the pointer (which will be a "foreign" address) and read/write a value from it?

@vitm, yes it is not posible in this way. The OS allows you to access only the current process memory address space (there are special win32 apis for accessing a different address space in some cases, but it is not something you can do trivially).

Added some more info about it to my answer.

@ wohlstad, and technically if I point from code to random memory cell of other process, then my process will crash? And from example of code that second byte could refer to another address space?

No, you simply cannot do that technically. Any address that you can possibly have in a pointer is always in your address space. The OS keeps a total separation between address spaces. A address X in one process is totally separate than the same address X in another (even if X is the same number).

@vitm Lookup the term "virtual memory" what you describe is completely impossible in normal user-mode code (not in the kernel/drivers)

@vitm this can get you started if you are using Windows: Virtual Address Space (Memory Management.
